# error in C codes from edition 3 of E Balaguruswamy book chapter-1 topic-subroutines

Tags: c, function, compiler-errors, printf, declaration

error in printf line, debugger says printf prototype .
can you edit the program in a way that it gives the expected value?

tried it on code::blocks, turbo c and c compiler online beta(android) i got error

```
/*program using function*/
int mul(int a, int b); /*declaration*/
main()
{
int a,b,c;
a=5;
b=10;
c= mul (a,b);
printf("multiplication of %d and %d is %d" , a, b, c);
}
/*main program ends*/
/*mul() function starts*/
int mul (int x, int y)
int p;
{
p=x*y;
return(p);
}
```

expected output- 
multiplication of of 5 and 10 is 50

Comment: If that's the code from the book, it is time to throw the book into the garbage.  The `main()` function is not allowed in C99 (it was OK in C90, as a grudging necessity to code that existed prior to the standard).  The `mul()` function needs `p` defined inside the braces.

Comment: I am looking at that [book](https://www.pdfdrive.com/ansi-c-balaguruswamy-c-language-d60362044.html), and remarkably that is exactly the code from the book (though the book at least has indentation).  The book title is "Programming in ANSI C" - an anachronistic term in itself, but has a copyright date of 2007 and 2011 in its 5th edition and this error has persisted..  It makes comparisons in that section to FORTRAN and BASIC as if it is likely that the reader is more familiar these languages!  Get a better book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function should be defined like

```
int mul (int x, int y)
{
    int p;

    p = x * y;

    return p;
}
```

That is, the declaration of the local variable `p` must be inside the body of the function.

And you have to include the header `<stdio.h>` where the function `printf` is declared.

Take into account that in general the multiplication of two integers can result in overflow. So a better function definition can look the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

long long int mul( int, int );

int main(void) 
{
    int a = 5, b = 10;
    long long int c = mul( a, b );

    printf( "multiplication of %d and %d is %lld\n" , a, b, c );
}

long long int mul( int x, int y )
{
    return ( long long int )x * y;
}
```